# CDN with View.aspx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, cdn

Is it possible to use CDN with for example View.aspx file

In my case I resize the image by parameters so if I pass: View.aspx?height=30&width=30&imageId=1
The image with Id = 1 and height = 30 and width = 30 will be returned.

Is it possible to avoid every time resizing + using CDN for this?

I see in the CDN only the option to setup the folder for the cdn.

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what "Is it possible to avoid every time resizing + using CDN for this?" means, but I will try to provide sufficient information for your scenario.

The Azure CDN can be setup with either Blob storage or a .cloudapp.net hosted service as your point of origin.  The CDN can use your query parameters as a differentiator for the origin, which means that all users who browses to azxxx.vo.msecnd.net/View.aspx?height=30&width=30&imageId=1 will get served the object directly from CDN (not going back to your origin for processing), but a user who accesses /View.aspx?height=30&width=30&imageId=2 would be requesting a new object and the request would be sent to your origin for processing.

As for the /cdn "folder" requirement when using a .cloudapp.net you can always use a URL Rewrite on your webrole origin in order to change it to /View.aspx.